# How can a Integer of 32 bit system and 64 bit system have same memory in Java

Tags: java, performance

For a Java Integer Object in **32-bit system** the memory is 4 Bytes(for Class Pointer) + 4 Bytes(for flags) + 4 Bytes(for locks) + 4 Bytes(for int) = **16 Bytes**. And in a **64-bit system** the memory of an Integer Object is 8 Bytes(for Class Pointer) + 8 Bytes(for flags) + 8 Bytes(for locks) + 4 Bytes(for int) = **28 Bytes**. Which gets padded to 32 Bytes. But how come a 32-bit system have 32 Bytes for an Integer Object.Is the remaining 16 Bytes are from padding?

If it is for padding what is the use of making it same as in 64-bit system. Because even if it was 16 Bytes(in 32-bit system) there won't be any problem in range.

For clarifications I would suggest the following article.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-codetoheap/index.html

Comment: The size of a Java `Integer` object is undefined. You are relying on documentation referring to one specific implementation, or possibly to no specific implementation, or to an 'example' implementation.

The Java Language Specification and the Java Virtual Machine Specification are both silent on this topic.

Comment: Please speak in terms of bits when speaking about under-the-hood JVM, just like they do in the article you mentioned. The term "byte" has a [long history of not being consistent between 6, 7, 8 and 9 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#History).

Comment: @EJP if so, are there any implementation specific resources that details about how this memory allocation is being carried out for that particular architecture/implementation? Or is there a way to find out for every specific implementation?

Comment: @siva just wonder, why would you want to know?